# Send and store an image using xcode

Tags: php, ios, xcode, uiimageview

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to upload an image through my first iOS App and I need some help because I'm a little bit lost at the moment. With my PHP file I can insert a new row in my database (user and password) but now I need to upload an image to my FTP and then copy the full URL into my database (is it going to be the profile picture).

I have tried some things but it didn't work and now I'm stuck on this. can you help me with that?
I would like to know if my code is fine for uploading a file and also I need to know how can I send a UIImageView "ImageView" throught the PHP file, store it and insert the full URL in my database.

***Updated with what I'm trying with the UIImage. Regards.***

**NewProfileViewController.m**

```
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 90);
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&image=%@",[_Username_register text],[_Password_register text],[imageData]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
```

And that's my "**register.php**"

```
    $DB_HostName = "localhost";
    $DB_Name = "db_name";
    $DB_User = "db_user";
    $DB_Pass = "db_pass";

    $userName = '*'.$_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    //$correo = $_POST["mail"];

    $sql = "select * from user where userName = '$userName'";
    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    $res1 = mysql_num_rows($res);

    if ($res1>0)
    {
        echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Este usuario ya existe"}';
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "insert into user values (NULL,'$userName','$password','','http://website.com/Background.png')";
        $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error());
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

If you can help I will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Regards.

Comment: Could you please elaborate in great detail on "I have tried some things but it didn't work"? That would help us get started in helping you!

Comment: I mean that I have tried to use some code from some posts in StackOverFlow but it didn't work, but I can't show you that because at the moment I have it working with username and password, and I just want to add the imageview without crashing everything. Thanks @RobertRossmann

Comment: Updated with what I'm trying with the UIImage. Regards.